# Is it possible to access Route parameter in twig template directly?

Tags: symfony, twig

A view element on my page depends on a route parameter and will render something if a route parameter is present. Is it possible to access Route parameter in twig template directly?

For example:

```
TestBundle_testroute:
    pattern:  /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Default:test, name: defaultname }
```

I would like to be directly able to access “name” route parameter in Twig. Something like:

```
{{ routing.name }}
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
{{ app.request.get('name') }}
```

Comment: thank you very much! Could you please point me to page in documentation that shows all the different variable that are available this way?

Comment: @DavidW: Global Template Variables: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html, and the getters of the request object: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I added `{{ app.request.get('name') }}` to my twig template but it only returns a whitespace (routes defined by annotations). Cleared cache and all... did i miss something?

Comment: Ah, this works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349188/how-to-get-at-runtime-the-route-name-in-symfony2-when-using-the-yaml-routes-desc

Comment: @AaL, you were looking for a route name, while this question is about accessing a route parameter named `name`. ;)

Comment: `{{ app.request.query.get('name') }}` worked for me (using Symfony 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same problem. To fix this issue I fist dumped the request object and go through the attributes. In attributes you can see all the available properties associated with the request which can be accessed by twig. For example

```
app.request.attributes('_route'); //gives you route name
app.request.attributes('slug'); //gives you path variable with in the controller with the name 'slug'
```