# How to get at runtime the route name in Symfony2 when using the yaml routes description?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, yaml, twig

Here you can find my *n*-th question on Symfony2.

I'm working with a [pagination bundle](https://github.com/makerlabs/PagerBundle/wiki) that uses the route name provided in the `routing.yml` file.
From my perspective, this approach is not flexible and lead to a dirty code, since if I change the name of the route, then I have to look at all the Twig templates or PHP files to update the route name. This is ok for small Web applications, but will provide such a bug for larger applications and also need an high burden for the developer.

So, I was wondering to pass a string variable **x** to the `Pager` object provided by the above mentioned bundle. The string **x** should be initialized within the controller and has to provide the desired route name as given in the `routing.yml` file.

Let me give an example. The routing file is the following:

```
//routing.yml
 AcmeTestBundle_listall:
pattern:  /test/page/{page}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:List:listall, page: 1 }
requirements:
    page:  \d+
```

Then the related controller is:

```
//use something....
class ListController extends Controller
{

  public function exampleAction($page)
  {
    $array = range(1, 100);
    $adapter = new ArrayAdapter($array);
    $pager = new Pager($adapter, array('page' => $page, 'limit' => 25));

    return array('pager' => $pager);  
  }
}
```

Then, in the twig template, the `$pager` receives the route name that refer to the above bundle

```
{% if pager.isPaginable %}
   {{ paginate(pager, 'AcmeTestBundle_listall') }}
{% endif %}
{% for item in pager.getResults %}
   <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Any idea of how to get the 'AcmeTestBundle_listall' string value at runtime just inside the controller?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `app` global variable that is available in twig to get the current route from the request.

```
{% if pager.isPaginable %}
   {{ paginate(pager, app.request.get('_route') }}
{% endif %}
```

More about `app` [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/GlobalVariables.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#global-template-variables).

Comment: Sure! Thank you so much! Fast and clear answer... very appreciated!

Comment: To add to this, if you need the route parameters, use app.request.get('_route_params')

Comment: Symfony stores the route name as an *attribute* of the Request, so it should better be retrieved as such: `app.request.attributes.get('_route')`. Avoid using the `Request::get()` method because it first tries to retrieve the parameter from the query parameter bag - the attributes bag is only used as a fallback. That said, using `Request::get()`, a user can override `_route` by appending `?_route=my_tainted_param` to the URL.