# How can i know which link i clicked in an HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, twig, blogs

I am using PHP and Twig to create a blog for practice, I want to be able to access a post for it to display completely on a new URL, for this I use a route to '/indiv' which using a controller renders a new page, what I want is to be able to access any post and display it using only one '.twig' file, however I don't seem to find a way to find out which post was clicked, I know it has something to do with $_GET or $_POST however I don't know how to get the id of the post, some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}

 {% block content %}
    {% for blogPost in blogPosts %}
        <div class="blog-post">
        <a href={{'/indiv' | url}}> <h2> {{blogPost.title}} </h2> </a>
        
            <form method="get"> 
            <lable for="id"></lable>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="GotoPost">
            <a href={{'/indiv' | url}}> </a>
            </input>
            </form>
            
            <p> Jan 1, 2020 by <a href=""> Alex </a> </p>
            
            {% if blogPost.img_url %}
                <div class="blog-post-image">
                    <img src={{blogPost.img_url}} alt="">
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**one way:**

you have to alter your route so it accepts a parameter

```
/indiv/{id}
```

and in your html you send the id of the clicked post

```
<a href='/indiv/{{blogPost.id}}>
```

**another way**:

as i can see in your code, you are sending data in a form so you can send the id of the post as well in the form using `<input type="hidden" value="{{blogPost.id}}"`

i never used Twig so the syntax might be wrong but this is the logic to be used.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your answer. Can i know how to access the id after i use it like this? $_GET['id'] for example? thanks again :) had no idea you could pass parameters through url.

Comment: hello i believe it is something like that `{{ app.request.get('id') }}`
based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630619/7354094)

Comment: You are only using plain `PHP` and not something like `symfony`, `silix`, ...?

Comment: just plain PHP due to practice since i am starting with the language

the method explained by George sounds correct, however it is not working cause of twig's syntax, will try to fix :)

Comment: UPDATE: did it, I did it instead of using {{ app.request }} since it wasn't working i parsed $_GET["route"] on my controllers, after that i just did the query and returned the post i wanted to show :) thanks a lot for your help guys!!