# Symfony Guard: Access route parameter inside getCredentials()

Tags: php, symfony, sfguard

Is there a way to access a route parameter from inside a custom authenticator with Guard?

In detail:

The instructions at https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html are submitting the API key as an HTTP header (`X-AUTH-TOKEN`). But how can you access the API key, when it's being submitted as a route parameter instead (i.e. the `{slug}` part of the route `login/{slug}`)?

In other words: How can you access a route parameter from within `TokenAuthenticator::getCredentials()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8630619/1668200 I found the answer myself:

```
$request->get('slug'));
```